# why isn't the natural height of a Frame updated immediately?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing a widget to display some lines of text (via a `Label` in a `Frame`) and will need to adjust the font size once the text height is larger than the height of the containing `Frame`.

In order to do so, I am querying `.winfo_reqheight()` for the `Label` and the `Frame` after the text has been updated, with the idea to reducing it and rewriting the text - in a loop, until it fits (any better ideas are warmly welcome)

Anyway, I wrote a test script to implement that feature but the height I get for the `Frame` is one-off compared to the one of the `Label` (after having updated the text).

In practical terms: the code

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("200x200")
        self.f = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.l = tk.Label(self.f)
        self.l.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.root.bind("q", func=self.addline)
        self.counter = 0

    def addline(self, event):
        mylist = list()
        self.counter += 1
        for _ in range(self.counter):
            mylist.append("hello")
        message = '\n'.join(mylist)
        self.l.configure(text=message, font=('Arial', 30))
        print("frame: {0} label {1}".format(self.f.winfo_reqheight(), self.l.winfo_reqheight()))

App().root.mainloop()
```

after three presses of `q` displays

[image]

and outputs

```
frame: 21 label 51
frame: 51 label 96
frame: 96 label 141
```

See how the size of the `Frame` is one off? What is the reason for this behavior despite both widgets being queried at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until event handler returns, changes made there are not updated.

But you can force update using [`update_idletasks`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method):

```
self.l.configure(text=message, font=('Arial', 30))
self.l.update_idletasks()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

[`winfo_height()` documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_height-method) also mentions  `update_idletasks`:

> Get the height of this widget, in pixels. Note that if the window
>   isn’t managed by a geometry manager, this method returns 1. **To you get
>   the real value, you may have to call `update_idletasks` first**. You can
>   also use `winfo_reqheight` to get the widget’s requested height (that
>   is, the “natural” size as defined by the widget itself based on it’s
>   contents).