# How to get the true current size of a Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `Frame` in the root window (the root window size is set via `.geometry()`) in which I have two `Label` which fill the `Frame`. I would like to know the current size of the `Label` in order to adapt the font size of its text.

[I tried `.winfo_reqheight()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970672/why-isnt-the-natural-height-of-a-frame-updated-immediately) but I cannot make any sense of the values which are returned. The example below exemplifies the problem I face (the three questions are in bold):

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
# top level frame, containing both labels below. Expands to fill root
f = tk.Frame(root)
f.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
# the condition for the two cases mentioned in the text below
if True:
    text = ""
else:
    text = "hello\nhello\nhello\nhello"
# two labels, the top one's txt will be changed
l1 = tk.Label(f, text=text, font=('Arial', 40), background="green")
l1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
l2 = tk.Label(f, text="hello", font=('Arial', 15), background="blue")
l2.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
# just in case, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru
for i in [f, l1, l2]:
    i.update_idletasks()
print("top label: reqheight = {0} height = {1}, bottom label: reqheight = {2} height = {3}".format(
    l1.winfo_reqheight(), l1.winfo_height(),
    l2.winfo_reqheight(), l2.winfo_height()
))
root.mainloop()
```

### Case 1: condition set to `True` (empty text string)

[image]

and the output

```
top label: reqheight = 66 height = 1, bottom label: reqheight = 29 height = 1
```

All the widgets are set to expand, so **how come their total height is 66+29=95 while the window is 200 px high?**

**How can I get the height** of the i) empty, ii) filled both ways and iii) expanded `Label` -- which I would keep as the reference (if the `Label` grows I will know that it must not exceed that reference)?

### Case 2: condition is `False` (multi-line text string)

[image]

and

```
top label: reqheight = 246 height = 1, bottom label: reqheight = 29 height = 1
```

**Why has the top Label crushed the bottom one?** Is there a mechanism which says *'expand as much as you can but be vary of the other widgets?'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reqheight](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_reqheight-method) is the *request* height -- the height that the label wants to be regardless of how it is put in the window. It is the size it requests when the geometry manager asks "how much space do you need?". This value won't change based on how you use pack, place or grid, or how big the containing window is.

If you want the actual height, use [winfo_height](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_height-method).

Comment: I checked `winfo_height` and it returns 1 (this is in the example code and output). I do not understand this return value because the docs say "Note that if the window isn’t managed by a geometry manager, this method returns 1" (ant it is manged by a WM). Nevertheless, to the question "how much space do you need?" the answer of a Label which is set to expand fill should be 'as much as possible', right? (from the docs you linked and which I read: "... The actual widget size is then determined by the widget’s geometry manager, ...")

Comment: It returns 1 if the widget hasn't been drawn on the screen yet. You'll need to call `update` rather than `update_idletasks`. Or better, wait until the window is visible and/or bind to `<Visibility>`. As for answering the question "how much space do you need" -- the label needs a certain amount of space regardless of the geometry manager, and that's the value that it reports. If the geometry manager says to expand or add padding, that doesn't affect how much space the label itself needs.

Comment: @WoJ: note that there can be a big difference between what a widget _needs_ and its _actual_ size. If I hand you an object that is 100cm tall, how much space does it need? 100 cm. What if I put it in a room that is 10,000 cm tall, how much space does it need? It still only needs 100cm. What if I put it in a box 10cm tall? It still needs 100cm.

Comment: Yes, though I am not sure why the geometry manager gives preference to some widgets vs. others. In my example the bottom one fits in the frame but is squashed by the top one which does not. I guess that this is how it is implemented (the first one has priority). Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot in my thinking.

Comment: @WoJ: The behavior of geometry managers is fairly well defined. What is not particularly obvious is what it does when there isn't room for all the widgets (ie: why the top widget 'crushes' the bottom one). At some point the containing widget just isn't big enough to fit everything, and the geometry manager has to remove space from one or more of the widgets. All other things being equal, it will start removing space from the last widget that was packed (ie: the one with the lowest stacking order).